# Salesforce1 publisher action cancel button result in blank page

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have notice that when i use a publisher action that does a redirect using the  sforce.one.editRecord, and when i click on save or cancel, it return back to the calling page, which is blank (normal because im doing only a redirection). How to capture if teh cancel button from standard page Icame from was hit? there is no return url i can specify using the sforce.one.editRecord function. Does anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I manage to do some kind of redirect, with a custom button on my page , that allow the user to be redirected properly. As i was using a VF page, i had the capability of doing this at least. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try subscribing to the `publisher.clearPanelState` event:

```
    // This subscribe fires when the user hits 'Cancel' in the publisher
    Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe({name: "publisher.clearPanelState", onData:function(e) {

        // do something here...

    }});
```

> Fired by the publisher when the canvas app/page is deactivated or
>   hidden. This can happen when the user selects a different application
>   in the publisher or after the Share/Submit button has been clicked.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_sdk_publisher_events.htm

http://res.cloudinary.com/hy4kyit2a/image/upload/s1_dev_cheatsheet_cheatsheet.pdf